# Copying matching fields from one object list to another object list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I have two list of objects. List1 and list2

Employee list from App1

```
list1 
[id=1, name=Thomas, country=null], 
[id=2, name=Smith, country=null], 
[id=3, name=james, country=null], 
[id=4, name=arun, country=null]]
```

GuestEmployee

```
list2
[id=3, name=null, country=JAPAN, address=abc], 
[id=2, name=null, country=USA, address=def], 
[id=4, name=null, country=ENGLAND, address=hij]]
```

list1 has name details and list2 has country details.
How can I copy country from list2 to list1 for corresponding object with Id as same as list1.

In sql its quite easy we can join by ID column and do it. But here am hitting seperate API to read list2.

I can do create map from list2 and have EmpId as key and keep getting object from map and set details to list1.

Was wondering is there any better approach to do this.

Basically I have to loop two times to get data into list1.

Loop1 to create Map and loop2 to copy fileds.

Comment: You can create a `Map<Id, Countr>` using the second list and then iterate over the elements of the first list to create complete objects as you perform a `get` on the map created.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create class for your entity
2. Create map `HashMap<Integer, YourClass> map;` for source data list. Use Id field value as a key in map.
3. Create `List<YourClass> list;` for dest data.
4. Iterate your dest list of item and use `get` method of map to quickly get the country of the Entity with that `Id`

```java
for (YourClass item : list) {
   item.setCountry(map.get(item.getId()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate both lists and check if the IDs are equal.

If you want to copy the list2 Country to list1 objects do the following

```
for (Employee e1: list1){
 for (Employee e2: list2){
   if (e1.getId()==e2.getId()) { //if its a String do .equals()
      e1.setCountry(e2.getCountry();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Employee employee : list1){
  for(Employee employee2 : list2) {
    if(employee.getId() == employee2.getId()){
      employee.setCountry(employee2.getCountry());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

short:
You take every employee from list1, search for an employee with the same id from list2 and set the County if they match.

Comment: Ioannis Barakos was 30 secs faster. XD